# GUI for creating complex HTML tables

Tags: open-source, gui, html-editor, table

Creating complex HTML tables manually can be cumbersome. Therefore I’m looking for a tool (with GUI *) that makes creating complex tables easy.

It should be possible to create any kind of table (e.g., with colspans/rowspans), not just the most basic/simple kind.

(* Note that I’m *not* looking for a different markup language which could be [converted to HTML](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/156/60).)

#### Creating a table (GUI)

MUST:

- allow to specify which columns/rows are headers (Export: `th`)
- allow to specify which headers apply to which cells (Export: `headers` and/or `scope` attributes)
- allow to use HTML when entering content (i.e., the tool shouldn’t convert `<` to `&lt;`)

SHOULD:

- allow moving columns/rows
- allow sorting columns/rows alphabetically

#### Exporting a table (HTML)

- Valid [HTML5](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/) snippet (`table` incl. descendants).

  - No need to validate HTML entered as part of the content.
- No ballast (no `style` attributes, no `class` attributes).

#### Formal requirements

- It must be **FLOSS** (can be a self-hosted Web app or a local client).

  - If it’s a local solution: I’d prefer GNU/Linux, but a solution for any OS is welcome.

Comment: I was about to propose Kompozer, but it does not have any feature to create TH elements visually...

Comment: Are you  1. Manually entering the data 2. Getting from spreadsheets  3. from access,mysql, or other database  4. Other   What OS are you running Windows,MAC,Linux

Comment: @cybernard: It’s for manually entering the data (for a static webpage); no need for data import or something like that. // OS: Personally, I’m using GNU/Linux, but I don’t want to restrict answers to this OS, so solutions for any OS are welcome.

Answer (score 1):

There is a browser based HTML editor called TinyMCE which is able to edit tables:

http://www.tinymce.com/tryit/full.php

Just go to the table column and hit insert table. Then you can edit that table freely with the table tools. When you are done, just click Tools->Source Code and copy the HTML source code. Not exactly only for tables, but it works.

You can download your own copy and host it on your webpage if you want.

***NOTE:*** It doesn't include all your sorting requirements and seems pretty basic...

**EDIT:** This one [here](http://truben.no/table/) satisfies all your requirements but is not a FOSS.