# Tool for saving webpages in XML format

Tags: html, offline, document-converter, xml

I want to create an offline app to show drugs information. The information I need to use is already available in [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_drugs). But at this page, there are so many subpages (1000+) to be saved and in my opinion doing this task manually is not feasible.

Also note that I should save each drug in a formatted element in XML (with certain schema). Now I'm looking for a tool to facilitate this task. Does such a tool exist at all or not?

**My Requirements**

1. Gets a HTML page(s) and creates an XML document
2. Preferably free
3. Windows or Linux based

Comment: **(a)** So the tool does not have to download/select all the drug Wikipedia articles, correct? **(b)** Which XML schema should be used, or should it use the HTML elements with the HTML namespace? **(c)** Should the tool work with a list of URLs, with only one URL, with a local file, with full text input?

Comment: @unor **(a)** If doing so it's better **(b)** A simple XSD schema, I think this is not matter **(c)** Working with a list of URLs is better but supporting files and other documents is also acceptable **(d)** Thanks for your response

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I doubt you will find an off-the-shelf tool for this purpose, this is IMHO a too specific requirement. But there a lots of frameworks for each major programming language which help you to implement a web "scraper" or "crawler" by yourself.

For example, googling for "python web crawler" immediately showed up http://scrapy.org/, looking for "java web crawler" gave a link to [crawler4j](https://code.google.com/p/crawler4j/). Using such a framework, for someone with >4K points on stackoverflow it should be a matter of a few days at most to implement what you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks dear Doc Brown and @unor, your answers are really helpful and valuable but I can't unfortunately accept both of them. In my opinion experiencing some programming for this task might be more enjoyable! so I've accepted this answer, however I really appreciate unor's answer

Comment: @abforce: maybe you can combine the two suggestions - write a crawler (using one of the suggested frameworks), which makes use of the  Special:Export feature.

Answer (score 4):

Not a general tool for this job, but a solution that converts Wikipedia articles to XML documents:

1. Go to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:Export
2. Enter article name(s)
3. Click at "Export"

(By entering a category name into the "Add pages from category" field, you can automatically export all pages that belong to this category.)

On http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Parameters_to_Special:Export you can read about more features of the export function that can be controlled by manipulating the URL.

The actual article content (included in the XML element `text`) is exported in MediaWiki syntax. On http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Alternative_parsers you can find various tools that convert this markup to something else, e.g., XML.

For example, [Pandoc can import MediaWiki syntax](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/172/60) and export to XHTML (which is XML).